# Asyncio: How to cleanup instance of class in __del__ method when we need to use async methods

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.8

Suppose a class which needs an async coroutine to cleanup:

```py
import asyncio                                                                                                          

class AsyncClient:                                                                                                      

    async def do_something(self):                                                                                       
        print ('Doing something')                                                                                       
        await asyncio.sleep(1)                                                                                          
        print ('Something done')                                                                                        

    async def cleanup(self):                                                                                            
        print ('Starting cleanup')                                                                                      
        await asyncio.sleep(1)                                                                                          
        print ('Cleanup in progress 1/3')                                                                               
        await asyncio.sleep(1)                                                                                          
        print ('Cleanup in progress 2/3')                                                                               
        await asyncio.sleep(1)                                                                                          
        print ('Cleanup in progress 3/3')                                                                               

    def __del__(self):
        **CODE_HERE_SHOULD_CALL_CLEANUP**
```

It is not allowed to use await in the dunder methods.

What should I put in the `__del__` method to allow a cleanup to be done in those 2 situations:

```
client = AsyncClient() 

async def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    await client.do_something()                                                                                         

asyncio.run(main())
```

OR

```
async def main():                                                                                                       
    client = AsyncClient()                                                                                              
    await client.do_something()                                                                                         

asyncio.run(main())
```

I tried to do the following which works for the first case but not the second case (I recreate a loop if the loop is not there anymore):

```
    def __del__(self):                                                                                                  
        print ('__del__()')                                                                                             
        try:                                                                                                            
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()                                                                             
        except RuntimeError:                                                                                            
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()                                                                             
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)                                                                                
            asyncio.run(self.cleanup())                                                                                 
            return                                                                                                      

        cleanup_task = loop.create_task(self.cleanup())
```

Comment: You probably want to use a context manager, rather than relying on `__del__` to be invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up shouldn't depend on when (or if) `__del__` is invoked. Define a cleanup method, and either call it explicitly or let a context manager call it implicitly for you.

```
import asyncio

class AsyncClient:

    async def do_something(self):
        print ('Doing something')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print ('Something done')

    async def cleanup(self):
        print ('Starting cleanup')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print ('Cleanup in progress 1/3')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print ('Cleanup in progress 2/3')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print ('Cleanup in progress 3/3')

    async def __aenter__(self):
       return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        await self.cleanup()
```

Then

```
client = AsyncClient()

async def main():
    await client.do_something()
    await client.cleanup()

asyncio.run(main())
```

or something like

```
client = AsyncClient()

async def main():
    async with client:
        await client.do_something()

asyncio.run(main())
```